# Is it possible to Fork (clone) a stream in java.nio (or regular java io)?

Tags: java, stream, fork, nio

Is it possible (using the standard java.nio api, without major hacking or proxying or facading) to take an output stream, and clone it, so that every write to the stream gets copied to two, independent output streams from one ?

Comment: I'm also wondering , in general, how such forking would be implemented in any Java api (not just nio), or if there are any real world programs that do such a thing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You would have to write an implementation of `WritableByteChannel` that delegated to both (all) target channels. Not too difficult, only one constructor and three methods to write.

**EDIT** You can do the same thing for streams by writing a FilterOutputStream derived class. Again very easy.

Comment: Sorry ---  I didn't mean to make the question specific to nio.  Any thoughts on regular io (see new title).

Answer (score 0):

Like EJP said it is very easy, but you could also use the commons-io library from Apache for that.

[TeeOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html)  - From the Docs: "Classic splitter of OutputStream. Named after the unix 'tee' command. It allows a stream to be branched off so there are now two streams."